# Asking for explanations of code examples

Tags: discussion

I've wondered about this for a while.  Are questions asking to explain some code example *good* questions here?

For example, I'm working through [Mastering Node.JS](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/mastering-nodejs) and am sometimes (regularly) finding that I don't quite understand what a code sample is trying to show me or find that I'm not getting results I think I should be or visa-versa.

Due diligence assumed, are questions with code samples from books and some explanation of why it's confusing me a good foundation for a question here?

Comment: Can be. Though maybe you actually need a tutor. (Error: Insufficient Data)

Comment: For the most part, it depends on the amount of code needing to be explained.

Comment: Follow the rules for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and be very specific about what you do and don't understand and it should be a fine question.

Comment: *"Due diligence assumed"* - that makes it an automatic no, since due diligence implies you reference multiple sources of information, not just the book. You see what the code sample works with and you research the individual parts in the wealth of documentation available. I'd find it hard to believe you cannot work out for yourself what a particular piece of code does unless you actually do *not* do your due diligence.